# Pie Chart with D3 and React

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

Hey guys I'm attempting to learn react and d3.js. Right now all my code is in a single js file. I'm attempting to marry up the array of colors with an array of objects that can then spit out into a pie chart with d3.

Earlier I was able to create an svg with 20 colored boxes side by side "the react way". Now I'm trying to port over a pie chart using the same type of structure to create the components.

Here's what I have.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    //import './index.css';
    //import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
    import * as d3 from 'd3';
    //import data from './listings.json';

    var data = [{"letter":"q","presses":1},{"letter":"w","presses":5},{"letter":"e","presses":2}];

    // Component that draws a single color swatch
    const Arc = ({ color, d }) => (
      <path className="arc" d={d} style={{fill: color}} />
    );

    // Draws an entire color scale
    class Arcs extends Component {
        pieWidth = 300;
        pieHeight = 300;
        radius = Math.min(this.pieWidth, this.pieHeight) / 2;
        colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
        width = d3.scaleBand().domain(d3.range(3));

        pie = d3.pie()
            .value(function(d) { return d.presses; })(data);
        arc = d3.arc()
            .outerRadius(this.radius - 10)
            .innerRadius(0);
        labelArc = d3.arc()
            .outerRadius(this.radius - 40)
            .innerRadius(this.radius - 40);


    /*
    //This bit was from an example and I have recreated it in the render function below
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 +")"); // Moving the center point. 1/2 the width and 1/2 the height


    //this bit is giving me trouble: the .data(pie).enter() I need to recreate in react somehow... I think this applies it to all the arcs at once but they get created one at a time in the render function so I'm stuck.

     var g = svg.selectAll("arc")
            .data(pie)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

     }
    */

        componentWillMount() {
            this.updateD3(this.props);
        }

        componentWillUpdate(newProps) {
            this.updateD3(newProps);
        }

        updateD3(props) {
            this.width.range([0, props.width]);
        }

        render() {

        return (
            <svg width={this.pieWidth} height={this.pieHeight}>
                <g transform={'translate(' + this.pieWidth/2 + ',' + this.pieHeight/2 + ')'}>
                    {d3.range(3).map(i => (
                        <Arc d={this.pie} color={this.colors[i]} key={i} />
                    ))} 
                </g>
            </svg>
        )
      }
    }


    ReactDOM.render(<Arcs />, document.getElementById('root'));
    //registerServiceWorker();
```

And here's the output:

```
     <div id="root">
        <svg width="300" height="300">
            <g transform="translate(150,150)">
                <path class="arc" d="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" style="fill: red;"></path>
                <path class="arc" d="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" style="fill: green;"></path>
                <path class="arc" d="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" style="fill: blue;"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

the 'd' value in the path element should start with an M or m and then the rest of the data needed to create the image. I think I'm approaching it wrong perhaps. Any step in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.